# jquery validation error during form submit

Tags: jquery, validation

I have made a script like this

```
$("#submit_butt").click(function(){
        $("#error_messgae").html('');
        //alert($("#deal_description").val().length);

            if($("#deal_name").val()=="") {
                var deal = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Name is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").html(deal);
                $("#deal_name").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#deal_name").css({'border':''});
            } if($("#deal_price").val()==""){
                var price = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Price is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(price);
                $("#deal_price").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            }if(isNaN($("#deal_price").val())){
                var price_num = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Price Should be a Number</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(price_num);
                $("#deal_price").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#deal_price").css({'border':''});
            }  if($("#category").val()==""){
                var category = "<li class='err-msg'>Category is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(category);
                $("#category").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#category").css({'border':''});
            }  if($("#deal_description").val()==""){
                var description = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Description is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(description);
                $("#deal_description").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } if($("#deal_description").val().length<120){
                var description_new = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Description Should be more the 120 Characters</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(description_new);
                $("#deal_description").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            }  else {
                $("#deal_description").css({'border':''});
            }  if($("#deal_instructions").val()==""){
                var instruction = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Instruction is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(instruction);
                $("#deal_instructions").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#deal_instructions").css({'border':''});
            } if($("#deal_tags").val()==""){
                var tags = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Tags is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(tags);
                $("#deal_tags").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#deal_tags").css({'border':''});
            } if($("#deal_days").val()==""){
                var deal_days = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Days is Blank</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(deal_days);
                $("#deal_days").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } if($("#deal_days").val()!="" && isNaN($("#deal_days").val())){
                var deal_days_num = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Days must be a Number</li>" ;
                $("#error_messgae").append(deal_days_num);
                $("#deal_days").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
            } else {
                $("#deal_days").css({'border':''});
            } 


    });
```

Now  I want to submit my form when everything is OK. how to do it?

Comment: why not use validate.js ? http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: are you asking what is wrong with your code? what is the expected behaviour, what is happening right now, what have you tried and what were the results? also please format that code, it's a PITA to read like that. a few linebreaks around the curly brackets woudln't go amiss :)

Comment: My problem is there is a space where I have to display the messgae. Which is Ok. But how can I submit the form after all checkings are OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be missing from your code is some indication of whether the validation has succeeded ot not.

Given your current code, I would place a variable `var validated = true;` at the beginning of your `click` handler, then set it to false each time one of your validation checks fails. For example:

```
var validated = true;

....

if($("#deal_name").val()=="") {
    var deal = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Name is Blank</li>" ;
    $("#error_messgae").html(deal);
    $("#deal_name").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
    validated = false;
}
```

At the end of your `click` handler you would then `return validated;`. If `validated` is false, the submission won't occur, and vice-versa.

I am assuming that the submit button is intended to trigger the actual submission of the form. If not, you would need to handle this appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submit button click event you can change it as below,

Sample example is as below.

```
$('#FORM_ID').submit(function(){
   //validation code.
});
```

**OR**

```
$(function()
{
    //we bind to the form instead of the form button
    //using .on() (jQ1.7+)
    $('#FORM_ID').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        //prevent form submission

        e.preventDefault();

        //do validation stuff

        this.submit();
    });
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#submitBtn').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do validation stuff...  
        $('#FORM_ID').submit();
    });
});
```

You can also use [**jQuery.validate**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin which also handle form submission.

Take a look at this [**Example**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html)

Comment: That `submit` handler doesn't return anything, and `preventDefault()` is never called, so the form will always be submitted whether or not the fields are valid.

Comment: I know I can use ajax but this is a modification work and I have to just make the checking and submit the form

Comment: if u don't wanna change code then just use $('#FORM_ID').submit(function(){
   //validation code.
});

Comment: please now check updated answer one out of three alternative will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$("#submit_butt").click(function(){
   if($(':text').val()=='' && $('textarea').val()==''){ // all other inputs too
       if($("#deal_name").val()=="") {
            var deal = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Name is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").html(deal);
            $("#deal_name").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#deal_name").css({'border':''});
        } if($("#deal_price").val()==""){
            var price = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Price is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(price);
            $("#deal_price").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        }if(isNaN($("#deal_price").val())){
            var price_num = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Price Should be a Number</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(price_num);
            $("#deal_price").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#deal_price").css({'border':''});
        }  if($("#category").val()==""){
            var category = "<li class='err-msg'>Category is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(category);
            $("#category").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#category").css({'border':''});
        }  if($("#deal_description").val()==""){
            var description = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Description is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(description);
            $("#deal_description").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } if($("#deal_description").val().length<120){
            var description_new = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Description Should be more the 120 Characters</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(description_new);
            $("#deal_description").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        }  else {
            $("#deal_description").css({'border':''});
        }  if($("#deal_instructions").val()==""){
            var instruction = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Instruction is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(instruction);
            $("#deal_instructions").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#deal_instructions").css({'border':''});
        } if($("#deal_tags").val()==""){
            var tags = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Tags is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(tags);
            $("#deal_tags").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#deal_tags").css({'border':''});
        } if($("#deal_days").val()==""){
            var deal_days = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Days is Blank</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(deal_days);
            $("#deal_days").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } if($("#deal_days").val()!="" && isNaN($("#deal_days").val())){
            var deal_days_num = "<li class='err-msg'>Deal Days must be a Number</li>" ;
            $("#error_messgae").append(deal_days_num);
            $("#deal_days").css({'border':'1px solid red'});
        } else {
            $("#deal_days").css({'border':''});
        } 
   }else{
       // if passed then submit
      $('form').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: What about the `textarea` ? Also I have multiple fields. So where should I put the `$('form').submit()` ?

Comment: that can be added `in the first if`

Comment: updated the answer and what kind of button you are using is it `type=submit` or `type=button` or `<button>`?